# Spinner appears empty but contains data

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm having an issue with my spinner. When I debug, I can see that there is data : my adapter contains objects.

[Debug spinner adapter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA6eq.png)

However, the spinner appears like it has nothing in it :

[My empty spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXoyu.png)

Here is the (supposed) interesting code  :

`

```
ArrayList<ActivityToSteps> activityConversionList;
ArrayList<String> activityList;  
ArrayAdapter<String> categories_adapter;

activityConversionList = new ArrayList<>();
activityList = new ArrayList<>();

categories_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, activityList);
categories_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


activityConversionList.addAll((ArrayList<ActivityToSteps>)task.getResult());

for(ActivityToSteps ats : activityConversionList){
    activityList.add(ats.getActivityName());
}

categories_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`

ActivityToSteps is a class I created, containing a String "ActivityName" attribute and a float "StepsPerMin" attribute.

I'm getting a list of ActivityToSteps from an async task, and I want a spinner containing all their "ActivityName", stored in the ArrayList "activityList" (which is not empty, but can't show screenshot beacause reputation < 10...).

I hope I've been clear enough!

Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: where u setting adapter to spinner like spinner.setAdapter(categories_adapter);

Comment: Wow, can't believe I forgot such a thing... I've been spending more than 1hour on that! Thanks a lot though...

Comment: welcome, it happens sometime :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check that you have passed your list to spinner adapter.

```
  your_categories_spinner.setAdapter(categories_adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

just forgot to set the adapter to the spinner..

```
spinner.setAdapter(categories_adapter);
```